# Why this select box is not displaying the 'Select One' option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I have a select box which is dynamically populated with `ng-option`. I want it to display "Select one" by default. I used the following html hoping to achieve this.

```
<select id="productType" name="productType" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-control"
    ng-model="context.product"
    ng-options="product.value as product.name for product in data.products"
    ng-change="loadAccessMethods()" required>
    <option value="" disabled>Select one</option>
</select>
```

But this is what I see when I run the application.

[image]

**Update : I am using Angular 1.6.5**

**Update : Vivz added a working code snippet with Angular 1.4.x in his answer. But it does not work with Angular 1.6.x. Can any one point out why this is broken in Angular 1.6.x ?**

```js
angular.module("App",[])
.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.context = {
    product: '',
    accessMethod: '',
    workOrderNum: 0
};

$scope.data = {
    products: [
        { name: 'ABC', value: '0', type: 't1' },
        { name: 'XYZ', value: '1', workflowType: 't2' }
    ]
};

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script> -->
    <script src=" https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js "></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <select id="productType" name="productType" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-control"
    ng-model="context.product"
    ng-options="product.value as product.name for product in data.products"
    ng-change="loadAccessMethods()" required>
    <option value="" disabled>Select one</option>
</select>
     </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try removing the class and check if it is coming. I just tested now and Select one is coming by default. Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @Vivz I am using bootstrap v3.3.7. I think this is something to do with Angular

Comment: I don't think so, I used your code and it is coming by default. Check below answer. This might happen if there is some problem with your css surrounding the select or label. Just verify.

Comment: @Vivz In your answer you have used Angular 1.4.x. I am using 1.6.x. It doesn't work on 1.6.

Comment: I think there must be some issue with the latest version of angularjs.https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a different approach like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.context = {
    product: '',
    accessMethod: '',
    workOrderNum: 0
  };
  $scope.data = {
    products: [{
        name: 'ABC',
        value: '0',
        type: 't1'
      },
      {
        name: 'XYZ',
        value: '1',
        workflowType: 't2'
      }
    ]
  };
  
  $scope.context.product1 = '';

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script> -->
  <script src=" https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js "></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1> First Apporach</h1>
    <select id="productType" name="productType" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-control" ng-model="context.product" ng-change="loadAccessMethods()" required>
    <option value="" disabled>Select one</option>
    <option ng-value="product.value" ng-repeat=" product in data.products">{{product.name}}</option>
    </select>
    
    
    <h2>Second approaach</h2>
     <span ng-init="data.products.unshift({ name: 'Select one', value: ''});"></span>
    <select id="productType" name="productType" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-control"
    ng-model="context.product1"    
    ng-change="loadAccessMethods()" ng-options="product.value as product.name for product in data.products" required>
</select>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Gurav Yeah. That's an option. I'm just trying to use angular best practices here. But if there is no way to get it done using ng-option. This seems the way to go.

Comment: @isuru-buddhika i updated the answer but i still think first approach is good.

Answer (score 1):

The above code of yours seems to work fine.

```js
var app=angular.module("App",[]);
app.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.context = {
    product: '',
    accessMethod: '',
    workOrderNum: 0
};
$scope.data = {
    products: [
        { name: 'ABC', value: '0', type: 't1' },
        { name: 'XYZ', value: '1', workflowType: 't2' }
    ]
};

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <select id="productType" name="productType" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-control"
    ng-model="context.product"
    ng-options="product.value as product.name for product in data.products track by $index"
    ng-change="loadAccessMethods()" required>
    <option value="" disabled>Select one</option>
</select>
     </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmm. I am using Angular 1.6. I tried your code in JSBin and seems it's working with 1.4 but not with 1.6.

Comment: I have updated question with your snippet with Angular 1.6.x. It's not working as expected.

Comment: I don't think there is a proper way to do it using ng-options in latest versions of angular. If you want to keep everything the way you wanted, then it is not posiible. But you can use dirty ways to manipulate your select options and make select one as default disabled option. But I think using ng-repeat will be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code It would solved your Problem

```
<select ng-model="context.product" ng-options="product.name for product in data.products">
<option value="" disabled>Select one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It didn't work with Angular 1.6 Mitul. What's the Angular version you are using?

Comment: I'm have used This version 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching the solution like below run snippet and let me know if it's working for you

```js
var app=angular.module("App",[]);
app.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.context = {
    accessMethod: '',
    workOrderNum: 0
};
$scope.data = {
    products: [
        { name: 'ABC', value: '0', type: 't1' },
        { name: 'XYZ', value: '1', workflowType: 't2' }
    ]
};
$scope.loadAccessMethods = function() {
console.log($scope.context.product);
}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <select id="productType" name="productType" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-control"
    ng-model="context.product"
    ng-options="product.value as product.name for product in data.products"
    ng-change="loadAccessMethods()" required>
    <option value="" ng-selected="true" ng-disabled="true">Select one</option>
</select>
     </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I removed product from your 
`$scope.context = {
    accessMethod: '',
    workOrderNum: 0
};`

and use `ng-selected="true" ng-disabled="true"` for disable and select your value.